# Create docker machine that exposes web root to host

Tags: macos, magento, docker-compose, docker-machine

I'm trying to use [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/alexcheng/magento/) image with docker-machine to create a local magento installation on a mac. I want the docker image's `/var/www` to be mounted on my mac's project directory (i.e. in a subfolder of my home dir on the host).

This is as far as I've gotten:

```yml
#docker-compose.yml
web:
  image: alexcheng/magento
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  links:
    - mysql
  env_file:
    - env
  volumes:
    - /var/www:/var/www
mysql:
  image: mysql:5.6.23
  env_file:
    - env
```

Note that I've added a line in there which should expose the docker image's /var/www to the host (i.e. the virtual machine). The env file contains various environment variables with the install scripts on the [docker image page](https://hub.docker.com/r/alexcheng/magento/) uses.

I then run some commands to create the machine, add a shared volume, permanently mount it, and run the install scripts

### Create the Machine and SSH in

```fish
docker-machine create magento
eval (docker-machine env magento)
docker-machine stop magento
VBoxManage sharedfolder add magento-machine --name www --hostpath ~/web/magento-machine --automount
docker-machine start magento
docker-machine ssh magento
```

### Set up the Persistent Shared Volume on the VM

```
mkdir -p /var/www
sudo mount -t vboxsf -o defaults,uid=`id -u docker`,gid=`id -g docker` www /var/www
exit
```

### Back on the Host, Run the Install Scripts

```
docker exec -it magentomachine_web_1 install-sampledata
docker exec -it magentomachine_web_1 install-magento
```

This works to expose `/var/www` on the magento machine to my project directory. However, this folder is not *docker's* `/var/www` but *the machine's*. the real htdocs is located at something like

`/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/1d17cf805c6925dead7d0fd1ba432d1b27f50a5a9240f585949aac6fad633790/var/www`

How can I run this image in docker-machine while exposing /var/www to my host machine?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://serverfault.com/ instead?

Comment: There are 8 docker-machine related questions on serverfault and 529 on stackoverflow.

Comment: That's great, but it doesn't mean that it is on-topic here. The question must be about programming for it to be on-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker only mounts shared data volumes after the container is brought up. The problem I had creating this local dev installation was that I tried to run commands in the shared folder before it was mounted. The solution was to relocate the commands which set up the web root to a shell script.

## Summary of steps to get it running:

First, clone down the [image repo](https://github.com/alexcheng1982/docker-magento) into project dir.

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
       - "80:80"
    links:
      - mysql
    env_file:
      - env
    volumes:
      - './htdocs:/var/www/htdocs'

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.6.23
    env_file:
      - env
volumes:
  htdocs:
    driver: local
```

### Dockerfile

```
FROM occitech/magento:php5.5-apache

ENV MAGENTO_VERSION 1.9.2.4

COPY ./bin/setup_magento.sh /usr/local/bin/setup_magento

COPY ./bin/install-magento /usr/local/bin/install-magento
COPY redis.conf /tmp/

COPY ./sampledata/magento-sample-data-1.9.1.0.tgz /opt/
COPY ./bin/install-sampledata-1.9 /usr/local/bin/install-sampledata

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/setup_magento && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-magento && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-sampledata && \
    apt-get update && apt-get install -y mysql-client-5.5 libxml2-dev && \
    docker-php-ext-install soap

VOLUME /var/www/htdocs
```

### bin/setup_magento.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /tmp
curl https://codeload.github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/tar.gz/$MAGENTO_VERSION -o $MAGENTO_VERSION.tar.gz
tar xvf $MAGENTO_VERSION.tar.gz
mv magento-mirror-$MAGENTO_VERSION/* magento-mirror-$MAGENTO_VERSION/.htaccess /var/www/htdocs

chown -R daemon:daemon /var/www/htdocs

sed -i 's/DocumentRoot \/var\/www\/html/DocumentRoot \/var\/www\/htdocs/' /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
sed -i 's/www-data/daemon/g' /etc/apache2/envvars
cd /var/www/htdocs

install-sampledata
install-magento

mv -f /tmp/redis.conf /var/www/htdocs/app/etc/redis.conf
```

### Create the machine

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox magento
eval (docker-machine env magento)
```

Using Virtualbox GUI (or on the command line, after you stop the machine) Create a shared folder named htdocs at /path/to/local/project/htdocs

### Bring up the machine and install

```
docker-compose up -d
docker exec -it machine-name setup_magento
```

here's a little fish script which removes any instances of the machine and does everything from scratch

```
function respawn
  rm -rf ~/web/magento/htdocs/*
  docker-machine rm magento -y 
  docker-machine create -d virtualbox magento
  eval (docker-machine env magento)

  set machine_ip (docker-machine ip magento)
  echo "$machine_ip magento.dev" >> ~/Library/Gas\ Mask/Local/Docker\ Machines.hst

  docker-compose up -d
  docker exec -it web setup_magento
end
```